# Assignment between generic lists

Tags: c#

How to assign same object list but in different namespace.
 list, list2

list = list2;

Cannot implicitly convert type 
`System.Collections.Generic.List<namespace1.MyData>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<namespace2.MyData>`

Comment: Can you clarify or post a bit of code? Are you just trying to copy the contents of list to list2?

Comment: if the type that's held by list and list2 is different (i.e. `List<int>` and `List<string>` you cannot do this, `namespace1.MyData` is not the same type as `namespace2.MyData`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds to me like a WCF proxy that has been generated and you want to reuse the existing class libraries instead of the proxy generated ones.

If this is the case, then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573935/silverlight-client-datacontract-and-private-readonly-members/5574174#5574174) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788432/dynamic-swappable-data-access-layer/2788701#2788701).

**Edit:**

as a follow up to this, occassionally you may be in the position where you can't reuse the common class definitions (in the case of Silverlight you have to create a whole new assembly which may not be practical). If you are in this position, there is another option: the proxy generated classes are defined as *partial*, so you can extend them with a `Clone()` or `Copy()` method that returns the identical object from the other namespace, with the values copied over.

Comment: good catch, certainly wouldn't have guessed this from the question

Answer (score 1):

If the objects can be cast to each other, you can do this, but it is looping though the lists and making a copy, it's not a direct assignment.

```
var newList = oldList.Cast<NewType>().ToList();
```